# How to load state from local storage before mounting the component in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to retain the background of the page which a user can choose from a radio button. The background changes with the option chosen but it doesn't retain its value when I reload the page and it also doesn't apply any of the specified colors but applies the color from the className until I click on one of the radio buttons.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    theme: true
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  const theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  this.setState({ theme });
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  localStorage.setItem("theme", this.state.theme);
}

toggleTheme =() => {
  this.setState({
    theme: !this.state.theme
  });
}

render() {
  let bgStyle

  if(this.state.theme === true){
    bgStyle = {
      backgroundColor:"#3B3B3B",
    }
  }else if(this.state.theme === false){
    bgStyle={
      backgroundColor:"#ffffff",
    }
  }

  return (
    <div style={bgStyle} className="overall"></div>
  );
}
}
```

The code to toggle the bg color is here

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
    handleChange = (event) =>{
      this.props.toggleTheme();
  }
render() {
       <form>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="Dark"
              checked={this.props.theme === true}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            Dark
          </label>

          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="Light"
              checked={this.props.theme === false}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            Light
          </label>
        </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Drop `console.log(this.state.theme)` in render and show every log

Comment: `App.js:81 true`
`App.js:81 true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `boolean` value stored in local storage, it will be returned as a `string`.

```
localStorage.getItem("theme"); -> "true"
```

It doesn't match any of your conditions in `render`. It works only if you toggle radio, since it's evaluated to `boolean` - thanks to the negation (`!`):

```
!this.state.theme
```

#### Solution:

Parse the value from local storage.

```
const theme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("theme"));
```

Comment: My suspcision but thank you for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score -1):

localStorage.getItem("theme"); will return a value not an object

```
componentDidMount() {
    const themeFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    this.setState({ theme: themeFromLocalStorage  });
}
```

Comment: That's not true, he's basically using a short syntax to declare an object.

Comment: @kinduser you are right. Just learned something new from a down vote